# playframework scala slick insert query without autoincrement

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, slick-3.0

Good Morning,

I've got the following code snippet:

```
def createResponsibleProcessTemplates(processTemplateId: Int, username: String): Future[Int] = db.run {
    println("Create Responsible TemplateId: " + processTemplateId + " UserName: " + username)
    (responsibleProcessTemplates
      returning responsibleProcessTemplates.map(_.processTemplateId)
      ) += ResponsibleProcessTemplateModel(processTemplateId, username)
  }
```

My Model is:

```
package models

import play.api.libs.json.Json

case class ResponsibleProcessTemplateModel(
                                  processTemplateId: Int,
                                  username: String)

object ResponsibleProcessTemplateModel {
  implicit val responsibleProcessTemplateFormat = Json.format[ResponsibleProcessTemplateModel]
}
```

And the trait looks like this:

```
trait ResponsibleProcessTemplateComponent {
  self: HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] =>

  import profile.api._

  class ResponsibleProcessTemplate(tag: Tag) extends Table[ResponsibleProcessTemplateModel](tag, "Responsible_ProcessTemplates") {
    def processTemplateId: Rep[Int] = column[Int]("processTemplateId")

    def username: Rep[String] = column[String]("username")

    def * : ProvenShape[ResponsibleProcessTemplateModel] = (processTemplateId, username) <> ((ResponsibleProcessTemplateModel.apply _).tupled, ResponsibleProcessTemplateModel.unapply)
  }

  val responsibleProcessTemplates: TableQuery[ResponsibleProcessTemplate] = TableQuery[ResponsibleProcessTemplate]
}
```

It should insert some data into a database table without generating an autoincerement id.

I don't get errors, but data is not stored in database.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution!

```
  def createResponsibleProcessTemplates(processTemplateId: Int, username: String): Future[Int] = {
     db.run(responsibleProcessTemplates.map(x => (x.processTemplateId, x.username)) += (processTemplateId, username))
 }
```

Comment: @Fellix how can I get the auto incremented id here after insert?

Comment: In this case there was no autoincrement.